# iconv will be deprecated in the future, transliterate

Tags: ruby, encoding, deprecated, iconv, transliteration

ruby 1.9.3 is warning about iconv deprecation, but I use iconv to remove diacritic to have plain ASCII from

```
Iconv.iconv('asccii//translit', 'utf-8', 'Těžiště')
```

returns `Teziste`. How I can obtain this using [String.encode](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-encode)?

Comment: what is your expected output and input?

Comment: Are you sure it was not `'ascii//translit'`?

Comment: @ArupRakshit: Think `'Těžiště'` is obviously the input and `'Teziste'` would be the expected output.

Comment: @sawa: no, it produce: `Encoding::ConverterNotFoundError: code converter not found (UTF-8 to ascii//translit)`

Answer (score 4):

If I had Rails (or just ActiveSupport) around, I'd do something like this:

```
ActiveSupport::Multibyte::Unicode.normalize('Těžiště', :kd).chars.grep(/\p{^Mn}/).join('')
```

to get `'Teziste'`. The `:kd` essentially [decomposes](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/tr15-29.html#Decomposition) your accented characters into separate accents and characters and then the `\p{^Mn}` removes all the non-spacing marks from the character stream and when you put it all back together with `join`, you get the unaccented string back.

If you don't have Rails or ActiveSupport handy, then you could use [`UnicodeUtils.compatibility_decomposition`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/unicode_utils/UnicodeUtils%2Ecompatibility_decomposition) from [unicode-utils](https://github.com/lang/unicode_utils) instead of `ActiveSupport::Multibyte::Unicode.normalize`:

```
> UnicodeUtils.compatibility_decomposition('Těžiště').chars.grep(/\p{^Mn}/).join('')
 => "Teziste"
```

I tend to have the ActiveSupport version patched into `String` in Rails-land:

```
def de_accent
    #
    # `\p{Mn}` is also known as `\p{Nonspacing_Mark}` but only the short
    # and cryptic form is documented.
    #
    ActiveSupport::Multibyte::Unicode.normalize(self, :kd).chars.grep(/\p{^Mn}/).join('')
end
```

so that I can say things like:

```
> s = 'Těžiště'.de_accent
 => "Teziste"
```

to strip out accents.

This approach won't handle everything but maybe it will do enough.

Comment: It is very close. But ... `'Groß'.de_accent => 'Groß'` (not `'Gross'` as in iconv)

Comment: @vitas: The problem is that what happens to `ß` is locale-dependent just like downcasing `SS` depends on the locale. This doesn't do anything with the infamous Turkish-i either. I'd recommend hunting around unicode-utils to see if there is anything in there that does what you need.

Comment: @Cœur Thanks for the heads-up, I updated both ruby forge links.